# ipmitool: "Insufficient privilege level" for administrator

Tags: ipmi, ipmitool

I'm trying to add the second administrator to IPMI:

```
$ ipmitool -I lanplus -H $ip -U ADMIN -P $passw user list
ID  Name             Callin  Link Auth  IPMI Msg   Channel Priv Limit
2   ADMIN            false   false      true       ADMINISTRATOR
6   TESTUSR          true    false      false      ADMINISTRATOR
```

I could login into web-ui and act as administrator using TESTUSR, but when I'm trying to use it with `ipmitool` - it don't work as planned:

```
$ ipmitool -I lanplus -H $ip -U ADMIN -P $passw chassis status
System Power         : on
Power Overload       : false
Power Interlock      : inactive
Main Power Fault     : false
Power Control Fault  : false
Power Restore Policy : previous
Last Power Event     : 
Chassis Intrusion    : inactive
Front-Panel Lockout  : inactive
Drive Fault          : false
Cooling/Fan Fault    : false

$ ipmitool -v -I lanplus -H $ip -U TESTUSR -P $passw chassis status
Get Device ID command failed: 0xd4 Insufficient privilege level
Get HPM.x Capabilities request failed, compcode = d4

Running Get PICMG Properties my_addr 0x20, transit 0, target 0x20
Error Response 0xd4 from Get PICMG Properities
No PICMG Extenstion discovered
Error sending Chassis Status command: Insufficient privilege level
```

Adding `-L ADMINISTRATOR` don't changes anything.

Any ideas why one administrator is "better" then the other one?

Answer (score 1):

There is a privilege level for each user in addition to the channel.  So one possibility is the privilege level for the user is not set correctly.

Looking through the `ipmitool` manpage, it appears the command you want is:

```
ipmitool user priv <userid> <privilege level> [<channel number>]
```

Trying it really quick, for some reason the privilege level has to be specified as a number (4 for admin).  You can use `channel info <num>` to find the LAN channel (see manpage for more info).

I can't seem to find the `ipmitool` options to see the present privilege level for the user on a channel.  Sorry if it's there and I can't find the right combo of options.  I am more familiar with `freeipmi`.  Using `bmc-config` you can see it like this (such as with user ID 3):

```
bmc-config --checkout --section=user3
```

Answer (score 0):

To set the `IPMI Msg` parameter to `true`, use

```
ipmitool channel setaccess <channel> <userid> link=off callin=off ipmi=on 
privilege=0x4
```

where  is the channel ID (usually 1) and  the ID of the test user, 6 in the case above.